Closed formula for Shapley value of elementwise multiplication
Let's assume we have a set of players $ N = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\} $. Each player $ i $ contributes a value $ v_i $. The value of a coalition $ S \subseteq N $ is given by the product of the contributions of its members, i.e.,
$ v(S) = \prod_{i \in S} v_i $
I am looking for a closed formula to compute the Shapley value for each player in this specific setting. The Shapley value for a player $ i $ in a cooperative game is generally given by:
$ \phi_i(v) = \sum_{S \subseteq N \setminus \{i\}} \frac{|S|! (|N| - |S| - 1)!}{|N|!} (v(S \cup \{i\}) - v(S)) $
Any insights or references to relevant literature would be appreciated.

Marginal contributions of player $i$ to the coalition $S \subseteq N \setminus \{i\}$ for your game can be written as $$(v_i - 1) v(S)$$ $v_i$ can be taken out of Sum in the Shapley value formula: $$\phi_i(v)=(v_i - 1) \sum_{S \subseteq N \setminus \{i\}}\frac{|S|!(|N|-|S|-1)!}{|N|!}v(S)$$ which leaves you with a weighted sum of all coalition values for coalitions without $i$. While there is a closed formula for sum of products of subsets, here we have a weighted sum which makes coming up with such formula way harder. Trying to reduce it  for 3 or 4 player games does not yield any interesting results.
PS: Your game seems to have interesting Harsanyi dividends which can be used to compute a Shapley Value with a different formula.

Consider a situation involving a set $N$ of agents, where a certain coefficient $a_{k} \ge 1$ is attributed to each agent $k \in N$. A tuple $\langle N, \mathbf{a} \rangle$ is called a product situation, in which each agent is attributed with a coefficient.
Let $\langle N, \mathbf{a} \rangle$ be a product situation, then there is associated a TU game $\langle N, v \rangle$ s.t.
$$ v(S):= \Big(\prod_{k \in S}\, a_{k} \Big)-1, \qquad\forall\, S \subseteq N,$$ is given. This definition avoids the inconsistency $v(\emptyset)=1$.
Moreover, it allows us to write the Shapley value more concisely, as
$$\phi_{k}(v)= (a_{k}-1) \sum_{T \subseteq N: k \in T}\, \frac{1}{t} \prod_{j \in T\backslash\{k\}} (a_{j}-1) $$
In addition, this game class belongs to the class of convex games since they are positive games.
For more information, see:
Pierre Dehez. Cooperative product games, 2023. Forthcoming in International Game Theory Review.
